# OmniScidb Expression Node is not supported

Tags: sql, expression

I am trying to use OmniScidb a GPU based database. i believe its sql command should be same with MySQL. My command is as follows.

```
SELECT rdate as rdate
      ,stime / 100 as Stime
      , ttime /100 as etime 
    ,c as endreturn 
      , up.steps as urange
      ,down.steps as drange 
      , Uptime.MinTime as utime 
      , Downtime.MinTime as dtime 
      /*, IFNULL(Uptime.MinTime, 2555) as utime 
      ,IFNULL(Downtime.MinTime, 2555) as dtime */

FROM HL as A

CROSS JOIN(VALUES(0.001),   (0.00125),  (0.0015),   (0.00175),  (0.002),    (0.00225),  (0.0025),   (0.00275),  (0.003),    (0.00325),  (0.0035),   (0.00375),  (0.004),    (0.00425),  (0.0045),   (0.00475),  (0.005),    (0.00525),  (0.0055),   (0.00575),  (0.006),    (0.00625),  (0.0065),   (0.00675),  (0.007),    (0.00725),  (0.0075),   (0.00775),  (0.008),    (0.00825),  (0.0085),   (0.00875),  (0.009),    (0.00925),  (0.0095),   (0.00975),  (0.01), (0.01025),  (0.0105),   (0.01075),  (0.011)) AS up(steps)
CROSS JOIN(VALUES (-0.001), (-0.00125), (-0.0015),  (-0.00175), (-0.002),   (-0.00225), (-0.0025),  (-0.00275), (-0.003),   (-0.00325), (-0.0035),  (-0.00375), (-0.004),   (-0.00425), (-0.0045),  (-0.00475), (-0.005),   (-0.00525), (-0.0055),  (-0.00575), (-0.006),   (-0.00625), (-0.0065),  (-0.00675), (-0.007),   (-0.00725), (-0.0075),  (-0.00775), (-0.008),   (-0.00825), (-0.0085),  (-0.00875), (-0.009),   (-0.00925), (-0.0095),  (-0.00975), (-0.01),    (-0.01025), (-0.0105),  (-0.01075), (-0.011)) AS  down(steps)  

OUTER APPLY (SELECT MIN(ttime) /100 AS MinTime FROM HL as B WHERE B.rdate = A.rdate AND B.ttime > A.stime AND b.ttime <= A.ttime AND H > up.steps ) as Uptime
OUTER APPLY (SELECT MIN(ttime) /100 AS MinTime FROM HL as C WHERE C.rdate = A.rdate AND C.ttime > A.stime AND C.ttime <= A.ttime AND H > up.steps ) as Downtime
 
 WHERE rdate / 10000 = 2011;
```

However, it returns

```
Expression node {"field":"rdate","expr":{"correl":"$cor0","type":[{"type":"INTEGER","nullable":true,"name":"rdate"},{"type":"INTEGER","nullable":true,"name":"Stime"},{"type":"INTEGER","nullable":true,"name":"ttime"},{"type":"FLOAT","nullable":true,"name":"h"},{"type":"FLOAT","nullable":true,"name":"L"},{"type":"FLOAT","nullable":true,"name":"C"},{"type":"BIGINT","nullable":false,"name":"rowid"},{"type":"DECIMAL","nullable":false,"precision":6,"scale":5,"name":"steps"},{"type":"DECIMAL","nullable":false,"precision":6,"scale":5,"name":"steps0"},{"type":"INTEGER","nullable":true,"name":"MinTime"},{"type":"INTEGER","nullable":true,"name":"MinTime0"}]}} not supported
```

How should i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by seting the allow-loop-joins flag to true

https://docs.mapd.com/latest/5_dml.html